# How to divide into sections

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Can you please help me. 
I'm reading a Python book for beginners and I want to test everything new I learn in a single notebook file. (I use Jupyter)

I have #comment then underneath example. I aim to use this notebook when I forget something.

how can I divide every chapter so it's independent and it doesn't affect the other exercises in the same notebook file?
I hope this question makes sense.

Kind regards,
Nesh

Answer (score 0):

You could break up each chapter into classes, that way (provided your syntax is correct) each class will not affect the others.  eg:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class chapter1:
    def run(self):

        #in this chapter I learned how to print to the console:
        print ("Hello world")

class chapter2:
    def run(self):

        #in this chapter I learned how to print variables
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        print ("%i + %i = %i" % (a,b,a+b))

#here is where you can run each chapter if you want
c1 = chapter1()
c1.run() # this will output "Hello world"

c2 = chapter2()
c2.run() # this will output "1 + 2 = 3"
```

edit: Sorry I didn't realise what Jupyter was when I answered this.  This answer is targeted at keeping all your notes in a single text file.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your time.